# Extraer items de Json

Tags: php

Como puedo extraer solo los items de este json?

```
{
    "prueva": {
        "codCompeticion": "1",
        "nomCompeticion": "Juvenil_1",
        "jornadas": []
    },

    "codCompeticion": "2",
    "nomCompeticion": "Juvenil_2",
    "jornadas": [
    {
        "item1": "1",
        "item2": "2",
        "item3": "3"
    },
    {
        "item1": "4",
        "item2": "5",
        "item3": "6"
    }]
}
```

Esto es lo que tengo pero no me sale

```
<?php

$calendario = 'http://juveniles.esy.es/2018/juvenil/aa.php';

$ch = curl_init($calendario);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$objeto = json_decode($data, true);
$items = $objeto['prueva'][1]['jornadas'];

echo $items[1]['item2']; // 5

json_encode($items); // [{"item1":"1","item2":"2","item3":"3"},{"item1":"4","item2":"5","item3":"6"}]

echo $items;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay algunos errores que no vez porque posiblemente tu PHP tiene deshabilitada la propiedad `display_error`.

Esta ubicación no existe en tu `json`:

```
$items = $objeto['prueva'][1]['jornadas'];//errado
```

No puedes hacer `echo` a un `array`:

```
echo $items;//errado
```

**SOLUCION:**

```
<?php

$calendario = 'http://juveniles.esy.es/2018/juvenil/aa.php';   

$ch = curl_init($calendario);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$data= curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);  

$objeto = json_decode($data, true);
$items = $objeto['jornadas'];

echo $items[1]['item2']; // 5

echo json_encode($items); // [{"item1":"1","item2":"2","item3":"3"},{"item1":"4","item2":"5","item3":"6"}]

?>
```

Comment: si, nos vamos acercando, pero lo que quiero es arreglar el json para parsearlo desde java, ahora obtengo esto---- array(3) { ["item1"]=> string(1) "4" ["item2"]=> string(1) "5" ["item3"]=> string(1) "6" } ----- me sobran las palabras array y string, es cosa de var_dump, como las quito?

Comment: dale entonces: **echo json_encode($items);** y borra la linea var_dump, rpta actualizada

Answer (score 1):

**Actualización**

No es necesario que utilices los comentarios al final de las líneas, sólo era una idea que te daba para que supieras lo que cada variable tiene adentro. Si lo que quieres es únicamente imprimir los datos de los items, deberías quitar todas las líneas con `echo` y dejar únicamente:

```
echo json_encode($items);
```

**Respuesta original**

El JSON que indicas no es un JSON válido. Supongo que es porque estás haciendo pruebas y debería ser realmente algo cómo:

```
{
    "prueva": [{
        "codCompeticion": "1",
        "nomCompeticion": "Juvenil_1",
        "jornadas": []
    },
    {
        "codCompeticion": "2",
        "nomCompeticion": "Juvenil_2",
        "jornadas": [
            {
                "item1": "1",
                "item2": "2",
                "item3": "3"
            },
            {
                "item1": "4",
                "item2": "5",
                "item3": "6"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Ahora, suponiendo que el JSON esté almacenado en una variable `$json`, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$objeto = json_decode($json, true);
$items = $objeto['prueva'][1]['jornadas'];
?>
```

Y ya en el arreglo `$items` tendrías la información que quieres, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
echo $items[1]['item2']; // 5
json_encode($items); // [{"item1":"1","item2":"2","item3":"3"},{"item1":"4","item2":"5","item3":"6"}]
?>
```

Comment: post1 editado, pero no me sale nada

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta, aunque parece que ya te respondieron lo que se debía hacer